# Guzzle Test mock oauth acess token

Tags: php, oauth, phpunit, guzzle

In my tests, I "mock" my OAuth process as follows:

```php
$oauthMiddleware = new OAuth2Middleware(new NullGrantType);
$oauthMiddleware->setAccessToken([
    "access_token" => "290473f650...",
    "expires_in" => 3600,
    "token_type" => "Bearer",
    "scope" => "*"
]);

$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create();
$handlerStack->push($oauthMiddleware);

$client = new GuzzleHttpClient([
    'handler' => $handlerStack,
    RequestOptions::AUTH => 'oauth',
]);
```

I follow the instructions given in [the repository](https://github.com/kamermans/guzzle-oauth2-subscriber#manually-setting-an-access-token):

```php
use kamermans\OAuth2\GrantType\NullGrantType;

$oauth = new OAuth2Middleware(new NullGrantType);
$oauth->setAccessToken([
    // Your access token goes here
    'access_token' => 'abcdefghijklmnop',
    // You can specify 'expires_in` as well, but it doesn't make much sense in this scenario
    // You can also specify 'scope' => 'list of scopes'
]);
```

But instead of using the manually set access token, it throws:

> No access token is present, and there is no way to obtain one with `NullGrantType.`

I traced the exception back to [`kamermans\OAuth2\GrantType\NullGrantType::getRawData()`](https://github.com/kamermans/guzzle-oauth2-subscriber/blob/master/src/GrantType/NullGrantType.php#L15). In the documentation, it says, for the exception not to be thrown, `setAccessToken()` must be called. But as you can see in my code, I do exactly that (correct me if I'm wrong). Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the Guzzle mock handler https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html

Comment: Thank you, but that looks like a workaround rather than a fix, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess it depends on what it is your testing. It doesn't look to me like your sufficiently mocking the oauth layer for it to be testable. My guess is the error is because an underlying dependency is not mocked. It's hard to tell because there's no test code.

Comment: @GerardRoche I wrote "mock" in quotes because I did that instead of mocking as it was presented as a convenient way in the README. What's wrong with that if it is explicitly stated in the repository as an option?

Comment: Could you provide the whole php code you are using and throws exception, I don't see any issue with second code block you provided. Something may interrupting here, if You provide your whole code and your composer.json file I can replicate your code and debug the issue.

Comment: @vahidkhroasaninejad Unfortunately, I can't. It's code, I wrote for work and the repository is private.

Comment: @shaedrich  can you just share the parts that doesn't expose anything and composer.json ?